# Tomcat 9 Rotate or Remove stdout log file

Tags: tomcat, log4j, log4j2, tomcat9

I am looking for a solution to remove the logs/stdout log file or rotate this file daily/ by size in Apache Tomcat 9.0.75. I tried removing java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler and setting java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF in conf/logging.properties file, but not worked for me.

Please share if there any solution

Thank you